FocusRequester() and LocalFocusManager not working properly in jetpack compose
I have two TextFields, to provide good UX, I tried to use keyboardOptions and keyboardActions properties of TextFields. I have tried as:
val focusRequester = remember {
    FocusRequester()
}

val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

Row(
    modifier =  Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    Column(
        modifier =  Modifier.weight(1f)
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(
                horizontal = 16.dp,
                vertical = 8.dp
            ),
            text = "Date",
            style = TextStyle(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
        )

        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(
                end = 8.dp
            ).focusRequester(
                focusRequester = focusRequester
            ).onFocusEvent {
                if (it.isFocused) {
                    showDatePicker = true //changing the visibility state
                } else {
                    showDatePicker = false
                }
            },
            value = inputDate,
            onValueChange = { inputDate = it },
            placeholder = {
                Text(text = "dd/mm/yy")
            },
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
                    imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(R.drawable.calendar_days_svgrepo_com),
                    contentDescription = "Date icon")
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onNext = {
                    localFocusManager.moveFocus(
                        focusDirection = FocusDirection.Next
                    )
                }
            )
        )
    }

    Column(
        modifier =  Modifier.weight(1f)
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(
                horizontal = 16.dp,
                vertical = 8.dp
            ),
            text = "Time",
            style = TextStyle(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
        )

        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(
                start = 8.dp
            ).focusRequester(
                focusRequester = focusRequester
            ).onFocusEvent {
                if (it.isFocused) {
                    showTimePicker = true //changing the visibility state
                } else {
                    showTimePicker = false
                }
            },
            value = inputTime,
            onValueChange = { inputTime = it },
            placeholder = {
                Text(text = "Time")
            },
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
                    imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(R.drawable.stopwatch_svgrepo_com),
                    contentDescription = "Time icon")
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = (
                KeyboardActions(
                    onNext = {
                        localFocusManager.clearFocus()
                    }
                )
            )
        )
    }
}

The above code do show Next and Done buttons, when Next button is clicked focus is not changed to next TextField.
Any thig missing, or I am doing it wrong please guide.

I think you need to add FocusDirection.Right rather FocusDirection.Next. because right will be suitable for using in row.

@ChiragThummar Thanks for your reply, I have tried bunch of options, the option suggested by you is also tried, but in-vain.

Personaly I would rewrite part of your code to:
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Next
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onNext = {
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
        )

Then you don't have the fuss of having to know which direction is right and you already set everything up with
val focusRequester = remember {
    FocusRequester()
}

And
Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester)
Is there anything, I don't understand, why you can't use this working way?
